# Asynchronous database operations in non-static method

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, multitasking

I have a database represented by EntityFramework and I am adding an elements to it in async Task. My method is in simplification like that:

```
    private async Task SavePoint(Point point)
    {
        using (var ctx = new testDBEntities())
        {
            ctx.Points.Add(point);
            await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```

However the Task is non-static and I am using it simply calling `SavePoint(point);` (without await), since I do not need to wait for the task complete. What I want is to save a point in background, and allow the user to continue his work, and do nothing when it's added.

However I wonder if using a database context in a few tasks (when user fast adds a few points) will not provoke a race condition in database deadlock? Does it ensure a Mutal Exclusion?

Answer (score 4):

> I am using it simply calling SavePoint(point); (without await), since I do not need to wait for the task complete.

Are you sure? You don't want to even *know* if the save failed?

You're probably better off putting the request in a `try` and at least notifying the user if their changes aren't being saved.

> However I wonder if using a database context in a few tasks (when user fast adds a few points) will not provoke a race condition in database deadlock?

It won't cause a deadlock, and in this particular case, there is no possibility of a race condition. This is because each of your database updates is just an `INSERT`.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592904(v=vs.113).aspx) for the more general case of handling concurrency concerns in EF.

Comment: Just a small note: insert can cause a deadlock for instance if there is an index to be updated and some other operation holds lock to the index.

Comment: However, if I want a `SavePoint` caller method to await, the caller method has to be async as well, hasn't it?

Comment: The best for me would be:
`private void AddPoint(Point point){

/* add to interface */
try{
await SavePoint(point);
} catch(Exception e){

/* raise event notification to pront on interface, but do not stop the app*/
}`
However await can be used only in async and I have a "never ending story".

Comment: @Niko, what kind of never-ending story do you have? It should be possible to mark all methods async down the call stack.

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov, thats the problem. "Down the stack". I want something like I have pasted above. call an async task from the normal method, but I cannot use await.

Comment: @Niko: 99.9% of the time, the best answer is to use `await` anyway, by finding a way to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `SavePoint(point)` without awaiting it causes a "[Because this call is not awaited, the current method continues to run before the call is completed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh965065.aspx)" warning in visual studio. On the page for that warning it states:

Consider this scenarios.

- The call to the async method starts an asynchronous task. However, because no Await operator is applied, the program continues without waiting for the task to complete.
- Calling method depend on the results of the call or, minimally, the called method is expected to complete before you return from the method that contains the call
- what happens with exceptions that are raised in the called async method. An exception that’s raised in a method that returns a Task or Task is stored in the returned task. If you don't await the task or explicitly check for exceptions, the exception is lost.

In your scenario you can move like this, it will work to execute asynchronously

```
Task.Run(() => SavePoint(point));
```

Comment: Why do you think it would be better to execute `SavePoint` in `Task.Run`? What will be the difference?

Comment: As he dont want to wait. It could be Task.Run(). Thanks I will update the answer

Comment: But again, what will be a difference? Why is this better than simply call `SavePoint`?

Comment: as far my understanding, If we dont queue that operation, main thread will leave method, it is not sure that it is fully completed. 

The savepoint operation should be completed before the main thread leave the method. Else it can\t be ensured that its completed even.

Comment: if u write a file WriteAync() and ur caller method doesn't wait it for complete. It can be ensured that ur operation is completed if you dont wait or queue to the Thread.Pool

Comment: I don't completely understand what you mean, but in both approached caller will know nothing when operation completed. `Task.Run` will only schedule execution on `ThreadPool`. From client perspective both approached will look same.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing different concerns together.

> What I want is to save a point in background, and allow the user to continue his work, and do nothing when it's added.

You can mark your event handler (I assume you execute your logic from event handler) async and then await your DB access operation. Marking handler async will make sure that UI won't be blocked during DB operation and user will be able to continue interacting with UI.

> However I wonder if using a database context in a few tasks (when user fast adds a few points) will not provoke a race condition in database deadlock? Does it ensure a Mutal Exclusion?

No matter whether you use await or not UI will not block and user will be able to initiate another operation that might cause a deadlock.

It is better to await your DB operation because it gives you possibility catch the exception and either retry or notify the user that something went wrong. If you don't await you will loose information about exception and application state will be inconsistent.

Just to reiterate, no matter whether you use await or not, the UI won't be blocked if that's your concern.